# Flutter Mock Amplify using Mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I am trying to write a test for this code, yeah it's not perfect...does anyone know if there is a way to mock the [Amplify.Hub.listen](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_auth_cognito/example) call that can answer with a `MockSubscribtion` perhaps? I tried using this `class MockSubscribtion extends Mock implements StreamSubscription<dynamic> {}` but but obviously that wouldn't work. There are some relevant examples [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/c773828dd91ded62e25eece9b8945f07fa551957/packages/amplify_flutter/test/amplify_hub_test.dart)... does any one know if there's a way to simply mock this call without stubbing out all the transient dependencies?

```
/// Emits [User.empty] if the user is not authenticated.
  Stream<User> get user async* {
    subscription = Amplify.Hub.listen([HubChannel.Auth], (hubEvent) async* {
      if (hubEvent.eventName == 'SIGNED_IN') {
        try {
          var amplifyUser = await _authenticationInterface.getCurrentUser();
          var currentUser = User(
              username: amplifyUser.username,
              id: amplifyUser.userId,
              firstname: null,
              lastname: null,
              grade: null);
          yield currentUser;
        } on Exception {
          throw GetUserFailure();
        }
      } else {
        subscription.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: So no body know any trick with mockito stubbing for this?